# Move Google Pub/Sub Messages Between Topics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

How can I bulk move messages from one topic to another in GCP Pub/Sub?

I am aware of the Dataflow templates that provide this, however unfortunately restrictions do not allow me to use Dataflow API.

Any suggestions on ad-hoc movement of messages between topics (besides one-by-one copy and pasting?)

Specifically, the use case is for moving messages in a deadletter topic back into the original topic for reprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use a Python script for that.
You can use the **PubSub CLI** to read the messages and publish to another topic like below:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
from google.cloud.pubsub import types

# Defining parameters
PROJECT = "<your_project_id>" 
SUBSCRIPTION = "<your_current_subscription_name>"
NEW_TOPIC = "projects/<your_project_id>/topics/<your_new_topic_name>"


# Creating clients for publishing and subscribing. Adjust the max_messages for your purpose
subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
publisher = pubsub.PublisherClient(
    batch_settings=types.BatchSettings(max_messages=500),
)

# Get your messages. Adjust the max_messages for your purpose
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(PROJECT, SUBSCRIPTION)
response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=500)

# Publish your messages to the new topic
for msg in response.received_messages:
    publisher.publish(NEW_TOPIC, msg.message.data)


# Ack the old subscription if necessary
ack_ids = [msg.ack_id for msg in response.received_messages]
subscriber.acknowledge(subscription_path, ack_ids)
```

Before running this code you will need to install the **PubSub CLI** in your **Python** environment. You can do that running `pip install google-cloud-pubsub`

An approach to execute your code is using **Cloud Functions**. If you decide to use it, pay attention in two points:

1. The maximum time that you function can take to run is 9 minutes. If this timeout get exceeded, your function will terminate without finishing the job.
2. In Cloud Functions you can just put `google-cloud-pubsub` in a new line of your requirements file instead of running a pip command.

Comment: thanks for script. it was tricky not working, until i wait for future (``future = publisher.publish(NEW_TOPIC, msg.message.data)``, then ``future.result() ``)

it may be improved further if put futures in array first, if you need task often

Comment: also, max_messages should be adjusted so that you do not timeout your ack deadline.
becaues it takes bunch of messages and, if sent slowly, you won't ack them properly (won't ack, speaking simply)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use snapshots, because snapshots can be applied only on subscriptions of the same topics (to avoid message ID overlapping).

The easiest way is to write a function that pull your subscription. Here, how I will do it:

- Create a topic (named, for example, "transfer-topic") with a push subscription. Set the timeout to 10 minutes
- Create a [Cloud Functions HTTP](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) triggered by [PubSub push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) (or a [CLoud Run service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs)). When you deploy it, set the [timeout to 9 minutes for Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) and to [10 minutes for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout). The content of the processing is the following

  - Read a chunk of messages (for examples 1000) from the deadletter pull subscription
  - Publish the messages (in bulk mode) into the initial topic
  - Acknowledge the messages of the dead letter subscription
  - Repeat this up to the pull subscription is empty
  - Return code 200.

The global process:

- Publish a message in the transfer-topic
- The message trigger the function/cloud run with a push HTTP
- The process pull the messages and republish them into the initial topic
- If the timeout is reached, the function crash and PubSub perform a retry of the HTTP request (according with an exponential backoff).
- If all the message are processed, the HTTP 200 response code is returned and the process stopped (and the message into the transfer-topic subscription is acked)

this process allow you to process a very large amount of message without being worried about the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new push subscription under the source topic.
- Specify an incorrect endpoint as the push endpoint.
- Select the topic you want to move as the dead letter topic(destination topic) of this subscription.
- After 5 attempts, you will get an error and the dead letter topic (destination topic) will be redirected.
- Now you can use Replay message or Snapshot to push subscription in source topic